# how to reset/clear the input field without reloading the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clear the input field of my HTML table without reloading table
In my HTML table i have three columns `ItemCode` `ItemName`  and `Quantity` the `Quantity` column is editable so i want to clear that whenever user clicks on clear button without reloading the page

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tableData = [{
      "Category Code": "C001",
      "Category Name": "Beverages",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C003",
      "Category Name": "Juices",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C004",
      "Category Name": "Soups",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C005",
      "Category Name": "Cookies",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C006",
      "Category Name": "Buns",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C007",
      "Category Name": "Breads",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C008",
      "Category Name": "Rusks",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C009",
      "Category Name": "Biscuits",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C010",
      "Category Name": "Puff",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C011",
      "Category Name": "Savouries",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C008",
      "Category Name": "Rusks",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C009",
      "Category Name": "Biscuits",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C010",
      "Category Name": "Puff",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C011",
      "Category Name": "Savouries",
      "Quantity": "0"

    },
    {
      "Category Code": "C012",
      "Category Name": "Cake",
      "Quantity": "0"

    }

  ]


  function addTable(tableValue) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Quantity'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
          tabCell.classList.add("dataReset"); //this column i am trying to clear/reset


          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        } else {
          span = document.createElement("span");
          span.innerHTML = tabledata;
          tabCell.appendChild(span)
        }
        if (j > 1)

          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");

      }
    }
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");
    table.classList.add("table-hover");

  }
  addTable(tableData);
  $("#clear").click(function() { //this to reset the data to 0
    $(".dataReset")[0].reset();
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
head.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,
table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

select {
  width: 283px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form1">
  <div class="container" align="center">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h6>OUTLET :</h6>
        <select style="font-family: Verdana;font-size: 8pt;">
          <option>JAYANAGAR</option>
          <option>MALLESHWARAM</option>
          <option>KOLAR</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h6>CATEGORY :</h6>
        <select style="margin-bottom:10px;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 8pt;">
          <option>C001</option>
          <option>C002</option>
          <option>C003</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 table table-responsive" style="margin-bottom:1px;">
        <table id="HourlysalesSummary"></table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
      <button id="clear"> Clear
    </button>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

another j query method i am trying to reset

```
  $('#clear').click(function(e){    

            if(confirm("Want to clear?")){
                /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
                $('#form1 input[type="text"]').val('');

            }                   
        });
```

the above one also reloads the page

am i am trying the write approach but not working it is,anyone have any idea  please correct me

Comment: For the individual control elements you've to save the default values to a JS data structure (object or array), and restore a value from that data. If resetting the entire form is OK, then you can do that by calling `form.reset()`, where `form` is a reference to the form element.

Comment: Try `$("#clear").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault() });`

Comment: @Teemu no i don't want to reset the entire form,i have mention which column i am trying to reset as 0,because that column in only text field

Comment: @JeremyThille i have tried that but it is only stooping the form from reloading not clearing the data

Comment: How is it possible? `.reset()` works, right? `e.preventDefault()` should have no impact on it, it should only prevent the reload (which is the default behaviour)

Comment: @JeremyThille no i think .reset in throwing error please check my snippet...and also i have added another method i am trying

Comment: Indeed. It prevents reload, and allows the following error message to be displayed : `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].reset is not a function`. jQuery objects have no `.reset` method, this is just not part of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to reset to 0 `<td>` elements you can set their values by using **.text()** property like following:

```
$("#clear").click(function() { 
    $('.dataReset').text(0);
    return false;
});
```

Here's a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc43y052/4/)** implementing the above with your code.

**EDIT**: If you want to implement a confirm box just simply do:

```
$("#clear").click(function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
       $('.dataReset').text(0);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Updated fiddle.

Comment: hey what if i want to display a confirmation box of want to clear or not then on ok clear the data...please help me little in this

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please accept it as @JeremyThille mentioned.

Comment: @MartinStoyanov sorry to disturb you but on clicking cancel of confirm button the page re lodes and set the data to 0 :(  .whenever you will be free please check once please

Comment: I'll check it, give me a moment. :)

Comment: Just had to move `return false;` outside `if` statement since by returning false we actually prevent the page reload and in the previous case it wouldn't reload only if user presses OK. Code and Fiddle updated. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

first i added type="button" to your clear button so it will not be treated as a submit-button:

```
<button type="button" id="clear"> Clear </button>
```

Then i changed your reset function to clear the values

```
$("#clear").click(function() {  //this to reset the data to 0
  if(confirm("Want to clear?"))
    $(".dataReset").text(0)
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c91xqmhw/6/)

cheers

edit: no need to loop, as Jeremy Thille stated in the comments

Comment: Or simply `$(".dataReset").text(0)`. No need to iterate

Comment: hey thanx its working fine..but what if i want to display a confermbox and ask user "dou you want to clear"  please can you help me little more please

Comment: Bind the `$('#clear').click()` to open this confirm box and then bind the button 'Ok' inside it to a function doing `$('.dataReset').text(0)`

Comment: @viveksingh if you want a customized box you will have to implement it yourself. if you dont mind the look, just take the confirm-function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: @viveksingh Your original question has been answered (you should accept the answer). This is a different question.

Comment: @JustAMicrobe  i am doing the same `$('#clear').click(function(){ 
    
    confirm("Want to clear?")
     $(".dataReset").each(function(){
         this.innerHTML = 0;
       });
     
         
   }); `  but data is not clearing

Comment: @JeremyThille i will for sure but a small doubt please

Comment: @viveksingh try this: $('#clear').click(function(){ if(confirm("Want to clear?")) $(".dataReset").text(0); });